# How to use delay to add/remove classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Inside the .click(function () {}); I am trying t oget it to remove a class, add another, delay a second, then reverse everything again. It seems so simple to me yet I am stumped on this broken function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var items = $(".tabs-group .sidebar ul li:not(:last-child) a");
    var prompt = $(".prompt-button");
    prompt.click(function () {
        $(items).removeClass("pulse").addClass("solid").delay(1000).removeClass("solid").addClass("pulse");
    });
});
```

Help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try placing the subsequent operation in the queue. Otherwise removeClass, addClass is not added to FX queues to have it delayed by applying delay directly.

```
$(items).removeClass("pulse").addClass("solid").delay(1000).queue(function(){
                               $(this).removeClass("solid").addClass("pulse");
});
```

You could do:

```
$(items).toggleClass("pulse solid").delay(1000).queue(function(){
                               $(this).toggleClass("pulse solid");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though [PSL answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20576086/2324107) is probably the best solution, here an alternative. You could create you own delay function since `.delay()` work only on queued elements.

Here an example :

```
(function($){
    if($ && !$.fn.wait){
        $.fn.wait = function(time, fn){
            setTimeout(fn.bind(this), time);
            return this;
        }
    }
})(jQuery)
```

After inserting this in your files, you could call it like that :

```
$(items).removeClass("pulse").addClass("solid").wait(1000, function(){
     this.removeClass('solid');
})
```

[See the code in action](http://jsfiddle.net/wuR82/)

Comment: Yup re-usable... :) I like it.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra $ in items

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var items = $(".tabs-group .sidebar ul li:not(:last-child) a");
    var prompt = $(".prompt-button");
    prompt.click(function () {
        items.removeClass("pulse").addClass("solid").delay(1000).removeClass("solid").addClass("pulse");
    });
});
```

Comment: While this is a good suggestion, it isn't an error or a cause of things not working correctly.